# two divs side by side with ellipsis - issue with min-width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs side by side.

Both divs must remain on the same line (not one under the other), despite the length of the contents of each div.

So I used the css `text-overflow: ellipsis` on both divs (cobbled from a different jsfiddle). This does work, except for one small issue.

How can I add a `min-width` to the 2nd div class : `.container > div:last-child` (this is the div with the yellow background)?

I have tried to add a `min-width: 150px;` to this css class, but this kills the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` effect.

I have attached a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6233114/btLsoppm/2/) as an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
.container>div:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  background: aqua;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  /*important*/
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}
.container > div:last-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  /*important*/
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
}
.container > div:first-child:hover {
  white-space: normal;
}
.container > div:last-child:hover {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="not_important1">
    employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer employer
  </div>
  <div class="not_important2">
    url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url url
  </div>
</div>
```

I will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Not all browsers are based on webkit. The standard value if `flex`, not `-webkit-flex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `width` property use the `flex` property.

This is what you have now:

```
.container > div:last-child {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto; /*important*/
     width: 150px;
}
```

Instead try this:

```
.container > div:last-child {
    /* -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto; <-- REMOVE */
     flex: 1 0 150px;
}
```

This tells the div to have an *initial width* of 150px, but enables it to expand with `flex-grow: 1`.

In effect, `min-width: 150px` and `flex: 1 0 150px` are the same thing.

Learn more about the [flex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) at MDN.